# C# How to detect if client socket need authenticating ssl

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

I tried to use single server to serve both pure C# socket client (without ssl) and secure websocket client (with required ssl - wss). How does my server detect which type of client to serving? My server is written in C# too.

I tried use the `Available` property of `Socket` class. Websocket clients often has larger value than pure socket clients, but it doesn't seem to work. The value of `Available` is not stable.

```
Socket ClientSocket = Server.Accept();
if (/* condition to decide type of socket client */) // I tried but not work: ClientSocket.Available > 100
{
    NetworkStream _stream = new NetworkStream(ClientSocket);
    var ssl = new SslStream(_stream, false);
    this.Authenticate(ClientSocket, ssl, ServerCertificate);
    // call StartClient() after authenticating successfully
}
else
{
    StartClient(ClientSocket);
}
```

Comment: The traditional approach is to use separate ports for insecure vs secure connections (e.g. 80 vs 443) - it can be the same server. I am not sure there's a way to handle both types of connections on the same listener port.

Comment: Everything else in logic code works fine if I can handle this problem so it's better and codeless when implementing follow this way.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError "*I am not sure there's a way to handle both types of connections on the same listener port*" - it is *possible*, but not *advisable*. It requires peeking (not reading) the first few bytes from the connection to see if the client is sending an SSL/TLS handshake, and if so then create the `SslStream`. `NetworkStream` does not support peeking, but `Socket.Read()` does, via the `SocketFlags.Peek` flag. It is fairly easy to detect an SSL/TLS handshake looking at the first few bytes to see if they follow the SSL/TLS protocol framing